# Replacing a 18650 battery that was being charged at 5 V

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging

I'm trying to change my wireless speaker's battery that uses one 18650 battery, but when I checked the voltage that goes to the battery while it is being charged, I saw that it was 5 V.

I know that the charge voltage should be around 4.2 V - 4.3 V only, so my question is: is it safe to just replace the 18650 battery? Or should I make adjustments to the circuit to prevent overcharging?

My wireless speaker is a knock-off brand so I'm not so sure about it's charging protections.

Comment: Are you sure 5V is what you measured at the battery or is it the supply voltage of the charge controller?

Comment: Perhaps the battery failed open circuit (?) In that case you'd be measuring the charge circuit's unloaded output (CC mode), for which 5V is not unreasonable. Replacing the battery would be safe in that scenario.

Comment: Are you measuring directly on battery contacts while charging? If you measure 5V on battery contacts themselves, it can burn or explode! If it's 5V going from charger to charge controller chip, it's OK and the way it should be, because charge controller IC will turn 5V into correct charging voltage.

Comment: @LukeHappyValley I removed the old battery and measured the voltage on terminal where the battery should be attached and it reads 5v.

Comment: After I attached the new battery. This are my voltage readings. I put the probe on the battery terminals.

Battery only: 3.6v
With charger: 3.7v

Comment: See @unimportant 's remark about open circuit. It seems like all is like it should be.

Comment: Thanks @LukeHappyValley, I guess I'll try to charge it now and just monitor the voltages as it goes.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my speakers are a knockoff brand, that's why I'm concerned.

Comment: Could you show a picture of the PCB?

Comment: It looks like the battery keeps charging, at the end I got 4.3v with charger and it was still charging. After removing it the battery voltage became 4.26. I'll re-verify with a fresh battery.

Comment: @JonathanS. I can't currently, tomorrow I'll take it apart again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your latest comment about charging at 4.3V, the situation is pretty clear: This charger doesn't properly implement the CC-CV charging that's required for Li-Ion batteries. It instead just provides a limited current to the battery irrespective of its voltage (I could imagine that it's just a diode and a resistor connected straight to 5V).

Throw it away, it's a bomb. (Or charge the battery outside of the speaker.)

Comment: Maybe the voltmeter is also a knock-off brand and its measurements are too high. 4.3V is only 2.4% higher than 4.20V. A proper Lithium battery charger circuit is suppose to monitor the charging current and detect when the current drops low which is a full charge then disconnect the charger. A simple charger circuit dont doo dat.

Comment: @Audioguru I'm not sure if there is an actual charger circuit but I might re-test again if I have more time.

Comment: @JonathanS Thanks for the input, I decided to just remove the battery and just use it with external power bank since it still works without the battery.